# Use Webpack Dev Server to serve non-packed files

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I currently use webpack-dev-server to serve a bundle of javascript packed by webpack.  There are a few files that I would like served via the dev server, but not bundled in the with the rest.  Is there a way to expose a route that does this?  For instance:

```
/bundle.js <--- normal webpack bundle
/other-resources/file-a.js
/other-resources/file-b.js
```

I've checked out the documentation but after reading it I'm not sure if it actually supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with the [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader), as follows:

```
require("file?name=other-resources/file-a.[ext]!./file-a.js");
```